# How to make sure Vue component doesn't show

Tags: vue.js

I am using a component that acts like a role crossway depending which role the user has and a `beforeCreate()` hook to redirect the user to the a specific route.

I don't want the component template to be shown when the user is redirected so a added an state inside `data()` called `showComponent` and set it to `false` and then added `v-if="showComponent"` to the main template container.

The issue is that somehow the component has time to be rendered (for a fraction of a second) before the user is redirected, when I am setting `showComponent` to `true` at the end of `beforeCreate()`. How can I make sure the template is not shown?

Here is the script code:

```
<script>
    export default {
        name: "role",
        data() {
            return {
                showComponent: false,
            }
        },
        beforeCreate() {
            this.showComponent= false;
            s_auth.get(false, true).then(response => {
                if (response.role.name === 'MANAGER') {
                    this.$router.push('/recipe-manager');
                } else if (response.role.name === 'CLIENT') {
                    this.$router.push('/client');
                } else if (response.role.name === 'JOE') {
                    this.$router.push('/joe');
                } 
                this.showComponent = true
            })
        }     
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Default value of `showComponent` is false so it won't render

Comment: @AlirezaHI At the end of the `beforeCreate()` I am setting it to true, so it is briefly shown before the user is redirected.

Comment: why don't you put `this.showComponent = true` in `else`. So it will render when there is no route changing

Comment: Thanks.... feels bad.

Comment: You can use meta on routes to allow and redirect depend of users role and state instead of that https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/meta.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `this.showComponent` to `else`:

```js
beforeCreate() {
    this.showComponent= false;
    s_auth.get(false, true).then(response => {
        if (response.role.name === 'MANAGER') {
            this.$router.push('/recipe-manager');
        } else if (response.role.name === 'CLIENT') {
            this.$router.push('/client');
        } else if (response.role.name === 'JOE') {
            this.$router.push('/joe');
        } else { // add else here to change showComponent value when there is no route change
            this.showComponent = true
        }
    })
}
```